# Jenkinsfile "JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE" does not work on Windows

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following jenkinsfile, that runs a python script in the background(it starts a server) and then run some tests on the server.
This works great when I run it on linux, however on windows it does not.
On windows the script just keeps running (not in background) and the tests can't run.
This is the jenkinsfile that works in linux:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('git') {
      steps {
        git url: '************my url is here'
      }
    }
    stage('start the service') {
      steps {
        script {
          withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontkill']) {
            sh "python3 app.py &"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('query service') {
      steps {
        Here I have some tests
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for running on windows:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('git') {
      steps {
        git url: '************my url is here'
      }
    }
    stage('start the service') {
      steps {
        script {
          withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontkill']) {
            bat "python app.py &"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('query service') {
      steps {
        some tests
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also checked it with BUILD_ID=dontKillMe instead of JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE, however it still did not work.
How can I run the script in the background in windows? Why doesn't the jenkinsfile work now?
Thank you

Comment: Ampersand operator works differently in batch files. It is used to run multiple commands in sequence if each command is successful. I believe you could run batch script in background using `start` command or even run `sh` script on Windows too.

Comment: Thank you! it works now that I run sh script on Windows. But is there a reason for it not to work as batch? without the ampersand.

Comment: Batch normally waits until the command ends, so `bat` step won't return.